# Как слить все элементы подмассивов в один массив

Tags: php

Вот сам массив:

```
0 => 
     [
      0 => int 904
      1 => int 928
      2 => int 937],
1 => 
     [
      0 => int 351
      1 => int 352
      2 => int 353],
2 =>
    [
      0 => int 903
      1 => int 972
      2 => int 974]
```

Мне нужно чтобы получилось вот так:

```
[0 => int 904
1 => int 928
2 => int 937
3 => int 351
4 => int 352
5 => int 353
6 => int 903
7 => int 972
8 => int 974]
```

Это можно сделать как-то без `foreach`?

Comment: что делать с дублями, если они будут встречаться?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский дублей не будет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `array_reduce` function, Luke!
Примерно так:

```
$fArr = [[904,928,937], [351,352,353], [903,972,974]];

var_dump(array_reduce($fArr, function($acc, $item){return array_merge($acc, $item);}, []));
```

https://repl.it/EIF4/0

Comment: Тот же форич получился )

Comment: @Naumov, перебор в любом случае будет, но есть разница между перебором на скомпилированной функции и перебором на пыхе своей конструкцией.